# Trying to use a SELECT method to display table data inside a listbox

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to use a method from a class called `studentHelper` to initiate a `SELECT` to then display the table data in a list box, the table is `person` and the column is `personID`

this is my studentHelperClass

```
class studentHelperClass
{

  /// <summary>
  /// The SELECT method for the student
  /// </summary>
  public static void selectStudent()
  {
      MySqlConnection conn = connection();
      conn.Open();
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
      cmd.Connection = conn;
      MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM person", conn);
      MySqlCommandBuilder sqlCmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adap);
      DataSet sqlSet = new DataSet();
      adap.Fill(sqlSet, "personID");
      conn.Close();
  }
```

and this is my form:

```
private void btnLoadListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     studentHelperClass.selectStudent();
 }
```

it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your helper method `selectStudent()` is not return any data or not display any data in the UI. it only fill 
DataSet.

You can return the dataset from `selectStudent` as below

```
   public static DataSet selectStudent()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = connection();
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM person", conn);
        MySqlCommandBuilder sqlCmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adap);
        DataSet sqlSet = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(sqlSet, "personID");
        conn.Close();
        return sqlSet;
    }
```

now in button click event set the `DataSource` of  `ListBox` like below, and also you need to set `DisplayMember` and  `DisplayMember`

```
private void btnLoadListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = studentHelperClass.selectStudent();
    lsbxTable.DataSource = ds.Tables["personID"];
    lsbxTable.DisplayMember = "Name";
    lsbxTable.ValueMember = "ID";
}
```

Comment: `myListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

 myListBox.ValueMember = "ID";`
what are these? I dont understand...

Comment: is this WinForm application? you need to tag the question correctly. do you have listbox in your Form? which column data you want to show in the ListBox? when Item selected Do you need to get value as another column?

Comment: yes it is a winform, an dI have a list box called `lsbxTable`, by my understanding you want me to change `"name"` to say a column called `"personID"`

Comment: `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` can set as Column names. set the `DisplayMember` as which column you want to display in the UI.

Comment: i think it means that the value of the row will be based on "ID" and in that row you will only show "Name" column

Comment: ok, I have received this error when I click the button:
`System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescripor`

Comment: @user2767155 check my updated answer, we will set the Table as `DataSource `

Comment: ok I'm getting a new error, but you did help with the original problem. thanks